# Заменить часть URL средством Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, url, redirect

Есть генерируемый URL:
site.com/category?slug=evakuaciya

Необходимо заменить на:
site.com/category/evakuaciya

При этом параметр "evakuaciya" всегда меняется, условно - значение не постоянное

Answer (score 2):

```
server {            
.....
        rewrite category?slug=(.*)$ category/$args last;
.....
}
```

что-то типа того

Comment: проверил, ваш вариант не работает

Answer (score 1):

Решено таким образом:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(\/category)\?slug\=(.*)) {
     return 301 $1/$2;
}
```

Comment: Автор Nginx советует не использовать if, если можно обойтись. А ниже написано как можно.

Comment: @TotalPusher а можете дать ссылку, где он это советует? Я бы почитал, а то я использую if )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вот [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/company/oleg-bunin/blog/313666/) со слов `Вот такая конфигурация, когда у нас два if (true):`. Вообще я эти слова слышал на конференции. Что-то типа "как работает if знаю я и еще пара человек"

Comment: @TotalPusher спасибо!